# ConcurrentHashMap vs ReentrantReadWriteLock based Custom Map for Reloading

Tags: java, locking, concurrenthashmap, reentrantreadwritelock

Java Gurus,

Currently we have a `HashMap<String,SomeApplicationObject>` which is being **read frequently and modified occasionally** and we are having issues that during the modification/reloading, **Read** operation returns `null` which is not acceptable.

To fix this I have following options:

**A. Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)**

Which looks like the first choice but the operation which we are talking about is `reload()` - means `clear()` followed by `replaceAll()`. So if the `Map` is read post `clear()` and pre `replaceAll()` it returns null which is not desirable. Even if I `synchronize` this doesn't resolves the issue.

**B. Create another implementation based upon  [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)**

Where I would create acquire `Write Lock` before `reload()` operation. This seems more appropriate but I feel there must be something already available for this and I need not to reinvent the wheel.

What is the best way out?

**EDIT** Is any Collection already available with such feature?

Comment: Your maps are effectively immutable, which makes them a perfect target for publishing via `volatile`.

Comment: **Effectively immutable** sorry I don't understand `immutable` that well... Could you please provide some hints???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are not sure as to how what Peter Lawrey suggests can be implemented. It could look like this:

```
class YourClass {
    private volatile Map<String, SomeApplicationObject> map;

    //constructors etc.

    public void reload() {
        Map<String,SomeApplicationObject> newMap = getNewValues();
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(newMap);
    }
}
```

There are no concurrency issues because:

- The new map is created via a local variable, which by definition is not shared - `getNewValues` does not need to be synchronized or atomic
- The assignement to `map` is atomic
- `map` is volatile, which guarantees that other threads will see the change

Answer (score 8):

Since you are reloading the map, I would replace it on a reload.

You can do this by using a volatile Map, which you replace in full when it is updated.

Comment: could you please explain in more details? It is somehow hard for me to reason why this will work. I do understand that volatile will guarantee visibility, but how a compound operation like clear than replaceAll will work? Thank You.

Comment: To replace the entire map, all you have to do is assign the new map to the old volatile reference in your field when you have built the new copy. i.e. you really are replacing all, even the map itself not just its contents.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a *lot* like [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), though it really depends how you're populating the map, and how you compute the values.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

The real question is whether or not you can specify how to compute your `SomeApplicationObject` given the input `String`.  Just based on what you've told us so far, it might look something like this...

```
LoadingCache<String, SomeApplicationObject> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, SomeApplicationObject>() {
         public SomeApplicationObject load(String key) throws AnyException {
           return computeSomeApplicationObject(key);
         }
       });
```

Then, whenever you wanted to rebuild the cache, you just call `cache.invalidateAll()`.  With a `LoadingCache`, you can then call `cache.get(key)` and if it hasn't computed the value already, it'll get recomputed.  Or maybe after calling `cache.invalidateAll()`, you can call `cache.loadAll(allKeys)`, though you'd still need to be able to load single elements at a time in case any queries come in between the `invalidateAll` and `loadAll`.

If this isn't acceptable -- if you can't load one value individually, you have to load them all at once -- then I'd go ahead with Peter Lawrey's approach -- keep a `volatile` reference to a map (ideally an `ImmutableMap`), recompute the whole map and assign the new map to the reference when you're done.

Comment: SomeApplicationObject is an Entity which is preloaded from DB when application starts and read from Map all the time... Occasionally System Admin can reload the values.